# Query tune table with 171 columns and 26 outer joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I inherited a seriously ugly safety issues management app that began life in SQL Server 2005, I believe. Now running on SQL Server 2008R2.

I seek advice in how to approach tuning a query on a table that's very wide, 171 columns, and has 26 outer joins using integer keys. The database contains 71 tables, containing a database total row count of a miniscule 79104 rows.  The database is well normalized. The wide table, `t_Issues`, is the main table that all the lookup and 1:M supplementary data tables join to. `t_Issues` contains only 3600 rows and the satellite tables used by the query only a max of 5000 rows.

When SSMS doesn't run out of memory, the query returns around 300 rows in 25 to 30 minutes. Apparently the PROD environment has a lot more memory because the query has never failed there. The plan shows scans on all the indexes, including the PK of `t_Issues`.

I've tried adding indexes, added/changed clustered indexes, filtered indexes.  No help. Breaking `t_Issues` up into 3 tables that are 1:1 with each other made the performance worse. Denormalizing some of the tables that are 1:1 helped by 1 minute, but that's it.

The question: can you provide any other tuning tactics that may be useful in this environment?

Comment: Are you able to filter down to 300 rows with the WHERE from just one or two tables?  Or does each table filter out a small subset of the records?

Comment: I'd break the 26 joins into a few smaller joins and create temp tables, so the final select could be joining on five or six tables instead of 26.  I've had that work wonders.  Either that or update your resume and move on.

Comment: I have no idea if this would help, but you could try using a CTE for selecting the ids from t_Issues which meet the criteria, then assembling the matching data from the other tables and t_Issues in the main select.

Comment: Dave, Cindy and Turophile--The 300 rows come from a previous query that captures all the Issues visible to the customer into a temp table from the available 3600 issues, perhaps that tactic would be useful when applied to a collection of smaller joins as well.  Great idea.  What the joins are doing is assembling the myriad data from child tables that apply to an issue.  An issue may use all the child tables, or none of them. Wonderfully consistent.

Comment: Liking that "update the resume" idea!

Comment: If you're joining against the temp table (or filtering with WHERE), make sure to add appropriate indexes or primary keys to the temp table.  You also might want to try un-clustering the primary key of any table that isn't the main table or where only a small subset of rows are used, and look for any index that might be made a "covering" index through use of INCLUDE columns, if only a few of the total columns are necessary.